# How to get another View in the Behavior?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Can I use a Behavior to get another View?
let me explain

```
public class EditorBehavior : Behavior<Editor>
    {
        public Editor EditorMessage { get; set; }
}

<Entry >
<Entry.Behavior>
<local:EditorBehavior EditorMessage=""/>
</Entry.Behavior>
</Entry>

<Editor x:Name="EditorMessage"/>
```

How to use the Editor in other view behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is fairly easy you will have to get it using a `BindableProperty`:

```
 public static readonly BindableProperty BindedViewProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                nameof(BindedView),
                typeof(Xamarin.Forms.View),
                typeof(EditorBehavior));

    public Xamarin.Forms.View BindedView
    {
        get => (Xamarin.Forms.View)GetValue(BindedViewProperty);
        set => SetValue(BindedViewProperty, value);
    }
```

Once you do that you can just pass your View using `BindableProperty` or `x:Name`

```
<local:EditorBehavior BindedView="{x:Reference EditorMessage}"/>
```

But make sure you understand the Behavior lifecycle before using this, Also it would make more sense if you do not share the View itself but the concerned property so you actually do not make changes in the view from somewhere else.

Comment: why GetValue(ListItemsProperty) not BindedViewProperty?

Comment: if I specify the view to Editor then change typeof(Xamarin.Forms.View) to typeof(Editor). public Editor BindedView {get=>(Editor)GetValue(BindedViewProperty);}  but I get a null instead of a Editor

Comment: That was a typo from my side sorry. Also, do not change the type from View to editor cast it later on in your code!!!

Comment: it worked thank-you .by the way .how to get the keyboard bounds?

Comment: Umm what exactly do you mean by keyboard bounds?

Comment: the height of the keyboards when I tap the entry or a editor

Comment: Umm, I don't think you can do that, I am not sure. Could you please tell me the requirement? Or add a new question with details?

Comment: when I click the entry I want to hide the entry and scale the editor aside the keyboard so I need to get the height of the keyboard